# Relocating back to India with my grand piano used for work. Do I pay customs duty?

Tags: india

If I use a piano for work, and I am relocating back to India after being abroad 50+ years, do I pay customs duty on the Grand Piano and what is the pe

Comment: I can talk about Brazilian laws. If you were living abroad and said it for the Government. When you will come back, do not need to pay customs duty.

Comment: This question is interrupted.  "what is the pe" ... ?